# Topshelf NLog - Windows Service (Console App) not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, nlog, topshelf

I've tried to implement `Topshelf.NLog` in my project.

Here is what I've done:

Throught NuGet packages I've added to my project `Topshelf.NLog`.

After that I've edited my `App.config` and I've added:

```
 <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
```

After that on my `Program.cs` I've added line :

```
serviceConfig.UseNLog();
```

But after this line above I saw that my console app is not working as expected..

Here is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                HostFactory.Run(serviceConfig =>
                {
                 //serviceConfig.UseNLog();

                serviceConfig.Service<ConverterService>(serviceInstance =>
                    {
                        serviceInstance.ConstructUsing(() => new ConverterService());
                        serviceInstance.WhenStarted(execute => execute.Start());
                        serviceInstance.WhenStopped(execute => execute.Stop());
                    });

                    serviceConfig.SetServiceName("FilesProcessor");
                    serviceConfig.SetDisplayName("Files Processor");
                    serviceConfig.SetDescription("Simple console app that works as a service.");

                    serviceConfig.StartAutomatically();
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

With `//serviceConfig.UseNLog();` commented I have output as expected:

[image]

When I uncoment `serviceConfig.UseNLog();` there is nothing in my console, so probably its not working as expected:

[image]

```
Here is my `App.Config`:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="Products.WindowsService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="Products.BusinessLogic.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <applicationSettings>


  </applicationSettings>

  <nlog>
    <targets>
      <target name="t1" type="File" fileName="C:\WhatEverServiceLogs.txt"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="t1"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>

</configuration>
```

Comment: 1. Try to add a Console-Appender, 2. Check the logfile - is it empty? 3. Unrelated: From experience - name your targets properly. "t1" will drive your future "me" crazy .

Comment: @Fildor Check the logfile - is it empty? - Log file is even never created

Comment: In that case activate internal debugging. Maybe there is a hiccup with the config.

Comment: @Fildor If I move  <section name="nlog" .. into the <sectionGroup .. I'm getting an error which says : Unrecognized configuration nlog, thats reason why I moved it out of <sectionGroup...

Comment: That's correct. That's where it belongs. I was talking about the internal logging of nlog. You can turn it on like this `<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging This saved me several hours of try-and-error.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.config only contains a file-target:

```
<targets>
  <target name="t1" type="File" fileName="C:\WhatEverServiceLogs.txt"/>
</targets>
```

Try adding the Console-target:

```
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="C:\WhatEverServiceLogs.txt" />
    <target name="logconsole" type="Console" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial